# CORS Issue in Web Console (angular js)

Tags: angularjs, wso2, cors, wso2-esb

I have a developed a web console in angular JS in which I am using post and put methods and making HTTP requests in which I send json and calling a WSO2 REST API to get response accordingly. Its running on server but I am facing CORS problem. I have add add extension in browser and enable it otherwise I get following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.197.200.100:8000/ManagementAPI/createuser. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.197.200.100:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is how I am sending request

```
CreateUser: function(adata) {
            var config = {
                headers :{
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
            var promise = $http.post(213.187.243.177:8283/ManagementAPI/createuser,adata,config).then(function (response) {
                return [response.status,response.data];
            },function (response) {
                   console.log("Error Returned" + response.status);
                return [response.status,response.data];
            });

            return promise;
        },
```

I have tried [ThisLink](https://samurails.com/tutorial/cors-with-angular-js-and-sinatra/) for solution but did not work. Need a solution for accessing it without CORS.

Comment: You need to handle it on the server

Comment: Their isn't any way to handle in code?

Comment: Rest API and web console both are running on same server.

Comment: what language you are using on server ? Just add header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin :*` to response headers from server.

Comment: are you using php for API ?

Comment: I am using WSO2 ESB.

Comment: You need to add CORS headers to the out sequnce of your `ManagementAPI` API. If you need a help on that, please post your synapse config.

Answer (score 0):

Set headers in back end for avoiding CORS issues .
Sample code in php is shown in below

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}
```